# android overlay several images

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to overlay up to around 200 images. I'm using the following code but on attempting to overlay the 3rd image, the first 2 go away and all that I'm shown is only the 3rd image. In reality, when I'm merging the 50th image, I'm really only dealing w/ 2 images: the one that has 49 images overlayed and the new image to overlay. Here is an excert from my hello world project:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(filename);

Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

Drawable drawable = imageButtonFrameView.getDrawable();

boolean isBitmapDrawable = (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable);
if (isBitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    Bitmap existingBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(95);

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(existingBitmap.getWidth(), existingBitmap.getHeight(), existingBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(existingBitmap, new Matrix(), paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(newBitmap, 0,0,paint);

    newBitmap = bmOverlay;
}

imageButtonFrameView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

By overlay in the context of I would have 60 images if I took a picture of an analog clock showing the second hand move. Overlay in the context when I put the 2nd image over the 1st, I will see the second hand pointing to the first second and second second of the minute. The 3rd image overlayed then I would see the second hand point to 1st, 2nd, and 3rd second. etc

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Are you wanting to make the existing compilation fainter on each overlay? If not, you should move `paint.setAlpha(95);` below drawing the existing bitmap to the canvas.

Comment: you're right dharms. That did the trick. Much thanks.